# Count the Distinct boolean values for each ID in unique Groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that first groups account ID's by product category and I then have a sub query that looks at each account ID and gives a boolean as to whether or not they have been approved for a service.

I am looking to add a column to the query that breaks down all the ACCOUNT IDs in each category and lets me know the percentage of approval for that category (amount of true results per account ID / total amount of IDS in that product category)

The data essentially looks like this;

```
| category      | number of account ID's in category  | 
|---------------|-------------------------------------|
|  Bikes        |              22                     |
|  Snowboards   |              10                     |
|  Skis         |              13                     |



| Account ID  | approved for service? | Category  |
|-------------|-----------------------|-----------|
|  12345      |        TRUE           | snowboard |
|  67891      |        FALSE          | snowboard |
|  17492      |        TRUE           | skis      |
|  42929      |        TRUE           | Bikes     |
```

Ideally I would then like the query to organize the 'approved for service' results by product category and give me a true percentage. In this case the end result table should look something like this;

```
|   Category  | number of account ID's in Category | approval percentage  |
|-------------|------------------------------------|----------------------|
|  Bikes      |                 1                  |          100%        |
| Snowboards  |                 2                  |          50%         |
|   Skis      |                 1                  |          100%        |
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select category, avg( approved_for_service = 'True') * 100
from t1 
group by category;
```

If `approved_for_service` is a boolean, then:

```
select category, avg( approved_for_service ) * 100
from t1 
group by category;
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution @gordonlinoff :)

I am getting this error when trying to average a boolean though - most likely because it is trying to treat the boolean as a bigint


`function avg(boolean) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: @MikeTaylor . . . In that case, no comparison is needed.